# How can I search Confluence pages referencing a particular user?

Tags: search, confluence

In Confluence one can mention user (link to user profiles) using `@`-mentions. This generate in the source of the page the following source code:

```
<ac:link>
    <ri:user ri:userkey="7adcb12b54a7421801558f952560024b"/>
</ac:link>
```

and this is visible on the page as a link:

```
<a href="/display/~USERLNFN" class="confluence-userlink user-mention current-user-mention userlink-0"
        data-username="USERLNFN"
        data-linked-resource-id="150351190"
        data-linked-resource-version="2"
        data-linked-resource-type="userinfo"
        data-base-url="https://wiki.swisscom.com"
        data-user-hover-bound="true"
        title="">
    @Lastname Firstname, Department
</a>
```

How can I search for all pages containing this reference?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed this can be on Confluence server 7.4.7, and so should be the same on most server/dc installations. This currently cannot be done on cloud.

Within the Confluence `Advanced Search` there should be an `Add a filter` button. Click that, then select `Mentioning User` and input one or more user names. That should return all mentions of a user, including in comments. You can filter out the comments by changing `Of Type` to be `Pages`

This also isn't a programmatic solution, but that would probably be a question of the best way to access all the pages, and then search them. Maybe download via API then Elasticsearch?